# Air conditioned made a sound while running and stopped working

Tags: electrical, wiring, repair, tools, air-conditioning

Air conditioned made a sound while running and stopped working,I guess its probably short circuited.How can I repair it by myself?

What all tools do I need?

Comment: What type of air conditioner? What is the make and model? Do you have any experience working on electrical and/or HVAC equipment? What did the sound sound like? Can you better define "stopped working"?

Comment: May have just been the thermal fuse on the compressor kicking in when it got to hot. Have you tried waiting half an hour, or several months! ;-) and then plugging the thing back in and turning it on? Such fuses usually reset themselves once the compressor cools down.

Answer (score 1):

I'd strongly consider getting a technician to have a look at it and repair it unless you are at least somewhat familiar with electrical work.